# Set a flag on Google Maps - Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, flags

I'm newbie in RoR.
I'm stuck in setting a flag (Image) on Google Maps at a point which is loaded from database (Latitude and Longitude).
Any help, please!

Comment: Does anyone know? I really need this for my assignment in school.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the embedded code from Google Maps, and add the lat/long with variables.
For example, say that your latitude is in the variable `@latitude` and longitude in `@longitude`:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+<%= @latitude %>+",+"+<%= @longitude >+"+(You+can+insert+your+text+here)&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
<br />
<small>
  <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+<%= @latitude %>+",+"+<%= @longitude %>+"+(You+can+insert+your+text+here)&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">
    View Larger Map
  </a>
</small>
```